# chaning git checkout behaviour in zsh

Tags: command-line, bash, git, zsh, auto-completion

I'm follwing [this link](https://gist.github.com/mmrko/b3ec6da9bea172cdb6bd83bdf95ee817) on how to use *git checkout* auto-completion for only local branches.

I first used it on my bash shell as follows (Used [this link](https://cmetcalfe.ca/blog/git-checkout-autocomplete-local-branches-only.html) as a reference. Also, commented out the original code):

```
_git_checkout ()
{
    __git_has_doubledash && return

    case "$cur" in
    --conflict=*)
        __gitcomp "diff3 merge" "" "${cur##--conflict=}"
        ;;
    --*)
        __gitcomp "
            --quiet --ours --theirs --track --no-guess --no-track --merge
            --conflict= --orphan --patch
            "
        # __gitcomp "
        #     --quiet --ours --theirs --track --no-track --merge
        #     --conflict= --orphan --patch
        #     "
        ;;
    *)
        # check if --track, --no-track, or --no-guess was specified
        # if so, disable DWIM mode
        local flags="--track --no-track --no-guess" track=1
        if [ -n "$(__git_find_on_cmdline "$flags")" ]; then
            track=''
        fi
            # __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_refs '' $track)"
            __gitcomp_nl "$(__git_heads '' $track)"
        ;;
    esac
}
```

and this works, and now I can:

1. use `git checkout -- TAB` and see `--no-guess`
2. `git checkout TAB` shows only local branches

However, moving to zsh, I can't make it happen. I tried copying the `_git_checkout()` to a new file (~/.zsh_functions) and to modify it in the same way, and then add a `source ~/.zsh_funcitons` in `~/.zshrc` and source it, but it didn't help...

The link I provided suggests editing */usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/git-completion.bash*, which I don't have...

How can I make it work oin zsh also? (more specifaclly, when `_git_checkout()` is called and from where. I know I somehow need to mimic the way bash looks at a command (e.g. `git checkout <TAB>`) and tries to auto-complete it, but I'm lacking something here)

Thanks!

The reason I'm asking is that zsh is realy nice in that it has an excellent menu I can go over using TAB once the `git checkout` presents its output, however, in bash, I can control the output and get only the local branches, so I want the best of two worlds. If the tab-menu thingy of zsh can be imported to bash easily, I would be fine with that too :)

Comment: Did you see [this comment](https://cmetcalfe.ca/blog/git-checkout-autocomplete-local-branches-only.html#comment-3810584334)?

Comment: not sure what comment you are rffering, but this is the link I said I used as reference or my bash auto-complete

Comment: Oh, the comments don't load automatically. If you click my link then load the comments, you'll see the one I mean, copied here: *Good news, it turns out there is now built-in support for ignoring remotes. You no longer have to modify the script. Put this in your ~/.bashrc: `GIT_COMPLETION_CHECKOUT_NO_GUESS=1`*

Comment: oh, yeah... saw it in another forum a few weeks ago. Didn't work for me

Comment: So that comment mentions the .bashrc, but did you try putting it in your .zshrc instead?

Comment: not working also for zsh :-( I never got this `IT_COMPLETION_CHECKOUT_NO_GUESS` to work